# Multiple string resource files with similar keys in Android

Tags: android, android-resources

I have an android application that needs to display strings found under the resources, but there can be multiple `strings.xml` files, i.e. `strings1.xml`, `strings2.xml` and so third. The string key can reside in different `stringsN.xml` files, now if a key is found in lets say `strings1.xml` it should be displayed without looking into the other string files with the same key.

Is it possible in android? 
I have done this thing in my .Net application but seems not doable in android. Infact, android gives the compilation error when I enter values against duplicate keys in multiple strings.xml files.

**EDIT**

The reason for doing this is, there are different clients running my application. Lets assume for clientA I added the key "company" with the value "ABC" and in my default strings.xml file there is already a default company name with the same key "company" but with the defualt value "Default Company". Now, if clientA opens my application the company name should be "ABC" and "Default Company" for clients otherthan clientA.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html.

Comment: all string resources are merged without considering the file name, so no, you can't do that.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible on Android.

You can only have duplicate resource names in different folders (`values-qualifier`). Even then, the strings aren't duplicated. They are prepared for localization, and only one will be loaded at a time.

If you told us why you needed this, we could perhaps suggest a better solution.

Comment: Can you even have multiple `strings.xml` files in the same folder like this? I've never tried but I didn't think you could

Comment: @codeMagic As long as they'r all in the values folder, and have unique and correctly declared `<string>` elements it shouldn't be a problem. The filename doesn't really matter. The contents' element and attributes is what Android looks at.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I guess I thought it looked for the `strings.xml` before checking the tags

Comment: @codeMagic file location:
res/values/filename.xml
The filename is arbitrary. The <string> element's name will be used as the resource ID. Check the topic under string heading.http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string- resource.html. So having multiple strings.xml should not be a proble, since android use resource id and not the filenaem

Comment: @codeMagic yup dude we can have multiple strings.xml files (obviously not with the same name) in the Values folder

Comment: I knew the element name was used as the `resource id`, I have never had a need for more than one in the same `values` folder so I just didn't realize you could do it. Thanks

Comment: @RaghavSood thanks for your answer, actually I need to display values against a key which can be in any strings.xml file. I'm editing my question to clarify it further